# MS Acess button to export query results to Excel

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a problem with adding a button to a MS Access Form which would execute a query and open the results in a new window (in whatever format).

The two main problems are:

1. The database is external and password protected
2. The user cannot see the actual SQL string as they would then get the
   password to the external database.

The below code unfortunately does not work.

```vb
Sub bQuery_Click()

    Dim StrSQL As String
    Dim username As String

    username = Environ("USERNAME")

    StrSQL = "SELECT EntryText, NameID FROM [I:\SharedDrive\Master DB.accdb;PWD=pwd;].Database WHERE NameID='" & username & "';"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, StrSQL, "I:\SharedDrive\file1.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to save the SQL as a stored query then pass the name of query into `TransferSpreadsheet` call, not *StrSQL*.

Comment: tried adding `Dim rst As DAO.Recordset` and `Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(StrSQL)` and subbing the StrSQL in DoCmd with rst, but still does not work

Comment: Is `Master DB.accdb` an external database?

Comment: Creating a recordset is not the same as creating a stored query.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able/willing to add the table you're querying as a linked table? That way, you can create the query in your front-end database, and just export that query, rather than having to hard-code SQL in VBA.

Adding the table as a linked table will expose the password on the `TableDef` object, but it seems like you're already exposing the password in VBA. If you haven't already, you can lock down the database to make it hard for the user to open the VBA IDE (there are a number of strategies to do this, such as creating an ACCDE file, password-protecting the module file, and just locking down ribbons and keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: The linked table is not really a solution, because the user can see only their entries (this is why I check the environ username in the code). It is a security requirement. The VBA code is already password protected as well.

Comment: You could still do a linked table, and have the query (in the front-end) have a parameter for username. The button would then get the username from the ENVIRON function and pass it to the query via the parameter.

Comment: Right, but I can't risk users finding out the password. Most of them are advanced Access users, so making it hard for them is not enough, it must be impossible. Right now I have only a form in one file, the VBA project which runs the INSERT command is password protected and the database is external (and also password protected).

Comment: @xLokos ... If not using ACCDE, give each user [runtime shortcuts](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/developer/runtime.html) of MS Access app, so they do not see any internals or code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a query in Access and change the SQL with each button click:

**SQL**

```sql
SELECT EntryText, NameID 
FROM [I:\SharedDrive\Master DB.accdb;PWD=pwd;].Database 
WHERE NameID='xLokos';
```

**VBA**

```vb
Sub bQuery_Click()    
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    username = Environ("USERNAME")    
    StrSQL = "SELECT EntryText, NameID" _
               & " FROM [I:\SharedDrive\Master DB.accdb;PWD=pwd;].Database" _
               & " WHERE NameID='" & username & "';"

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")
    qdef.SQL = strSQL
    Set qdef = Nothing         'SAVES QUERY

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                              "mySavedQuery", _
                              "I:\SharedDrive\file1.xlsx"    
End Sub
```